# Submitting radio inputs with ReactJs and setting active class to the current selection

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to submit the event_type attached to the option chosen from the radio buttons. For example if "professional" is the chosen option, I would like to set the event_type to that on the submitted data. Also setting the "active" class to the label that is currently selected. I am trying to figure out how to do that. Any help? Thanks

```
<label htmlFor="professional" className="EventTypeFieldButton EventTypeFieldProfessional active">
  <span className="TypeDot"></span>Professional
</label>
<input type="radio" name="event_type" id="professional" value="professional" />
<label htmlFor="academic" className="EventTypeFieldButton EventTypeFieldAcademic">
  <span className="TypeDot"></span>Academic
</label>
<input type="radio" name="event_type" id="academic" value="academic" />
<label htmlFor="miscellaneous" className="EventTypeFieldButton EventTypeFieldMiscellaneous">
  <span className="TypeDot"></span>Miscellaneous
</label>
<input type="radio" name="event_type" id="miscellaneous" value="miscellaneous" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var MyComponent = React.createClass({

    render: function() {
    <label className={this.state.isActive}>
            <input type="radio" name="event_type" id="professional" value="professional" onChange={this._onselectRadio(e)} />
    </label>

    },

    _onselectRadio: function(e) {
        var event_type= e.target.name;
        // submit stuff
        this.setState({
            isActive = "active"
        });
    }



});
```

Since you have several label you'll have to render your radio inputs dynamically and check if e.target.name is equal to your label id/name , something like that.